# Vectorize a Newton method in Python/Numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to figure out if Python/Numpy is a viable alternative to develop my numerical software which is already available in C++. In order to get performance in Python/Numpy, one need to "vectorize" the code. But it turns out that as soon as I move away from very simple examples, I struggle to vectorize the code (I am not talking about SIMD instructions but "efficient Numpy code" without loops). Here is an algorithm that I want to get efficiently in Python/Numpy.

1. Create an numpy array containing: 1.0, 1.0 + 1/n, 1.0 + 2/n, ..., 2.0
2. For every u in the array, compute the root of x^2 - u, using a Newton method, stopping when |dx| <= 1.0e-7. Store the result in an array result.
3. Sum all the elements of the result array

Here is the algorithm in Python I want to speed up

```
import numpy as np

n = 1000000
data = np.arange(1.0, 2.0, 1.0 / n)

def newton(u):
  x = 2.0
  while True:
    f = x**2 - u
    df_dx = 2 * x
    dx = f / df_dx
    if (abs(dx) <= 1.0e-7):
      break
    x -= dx
  return x

  result = map(newton, data)

  print result[n - 1]
```

Here is a version of the algorithm in C++11

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

int main (int argc, char const *argv[]) {
  auto n = std::size_t{100000000};

  auto v = std::vector<double>(n + 1);
  for(size_t k = 0; k < v.size(); ++k) {
    v[k] = 1.0 + static_cast<double>(k) / n;
  }

  auto result = std::vector<double>(n + 1);
  for(size_t k = 0; k < v.size(); ++k) {
    auto x = double{2.0};
    while(true) {
      auto f = double{x * x - v[k]};
      auto df_dx = double{2 * x};
      auto dx = double{f / df_dx};
      if (std::abs(dx) <= 1.0e-7) {
        break;
      }
      x -= dx;
    }
    result[k] = x;
  }

  auto somme = double{0.0};
  for(size_t k = 0; k < result.size(); ++k) {
    somme += result[k];
  }

  std::cout << somme << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

It takes 2.9 seconds to run on my machine. Is there a way to make a fast Python/Numpy algorithm that does the same thing (I am willing to get something that is less than 5 times slower).

Thanks.

Comment: The nice thing about numpy is that it does the vectorization behind the scenes, eliminating a lot (but not all) of the optimizations you'd need to do when writing C++, for example. You definitely need to make use of all of numpy's tools to get the most performant code, of course, like using `ndarray`s in place of lists of lists of lists, for example.

Comment: @MattDMo: I am looking for an actual efficient code. I just don't know how to do it that's why I am asking for help.

Comment: 'vectorization' is difficult with serial operations - ones where the calculation in step `i` depends on results from step `i-1`.  It is easier when all the steps can be done in parallel - i.e. where the order of evaluation does not matter.

Comment: @hpaulj: It's not the case here as newton(u1) and newton(u2) are totally independent. It's just that there is no way to do that efficiently in Python/Numpy. The only solution I found uses Cython or Numba which is a no go for me. I don't want to "hack" for something that simple.

Comment: Within the `newton` loop, `x` at one step depends on `x` from the previous (`x -= dx` and `dx` itself is a function of `x`).  That's what I mean by a serial or iterative solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can do step 1. with numpy efficiently:

```
1.0 + np.arange(n + 1) / n
```

however I think you would need the np.vectorize() method to feed back x into your calculated values and it's not an efficient function (basically a wrapper for a python loop). If you can use scipy then there are built in methods that might do what you want http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.newton.html

EDIT: Having thought a bit more about this I followed up on @ev-br's point and tried some alternatives. The masking uses too much processing but the abs().max() is pretty fast so a compromise might be to "divide the problem into blocks" both in the 1st dimension of the array and in iteration direction. The following doesn't do too badly (< 20s) on my pretty low power laptop - certainly much faster than np.vectorize() or any of the scipy solving systems I could find. (If I set m too big it runs out of something (memory?) and grinds to a complete halt!)

```
n = 100000000
m = 5000000

block = 3
u = 1.0 + np.arange(n + 1) / n
x = np.full(u.shape, 2.0)
dx = np.ones(u.shape)

for i in range(0, n, m):
  while np.abs(dx[i:i+m]).max() > 1.0e-7:
    for j in range(block):
      dx[i:i+m] = (x[i:i+m] ** 2 - u[i:i+m]) / (2 * x[i:i+m])
      x[i:i+m] -= dx[i:i+m]
```

Comment: The bottleneck is the Newton method, and scipy.optimize.newton is of no help as the Newton method stopping criteria is going to stop at different iterations count depending on u.

Comment: yes newton might not be the right function, you could use ``optimize.fsolve(func, np.full(data.shape, 2.0), data)`` but it's quite a bit slower than simply putting your function into np.vectorize() and that's a lot slower than c++. Presumably you don't want to really solve x**2 using a numerical method, that's just a place holder for something with non trivial roots. Otherwise you could just do ``(1.0 + np.arange(n + 1) / n) ** 0.5``

Answer (score 1):

Here's a toy example. Notice that often vectorization means writing your code as if you're manipulating numbers, and letting numpy do its magic:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([1., 2., 3.])
>>> def f(x):
...    return x**2 - a, 2.*x    # function and derivative
>>>
>>> def newt(f, x0):
...    x = np.asarray(x0)
...    for _ in range(5):    # hardcode the number of iterations (I know)
...        v, dv = f(x)
...        x -=  v / dv
...    return x
>>> 
>>> newt(f, [1., 1., 1.])
array([ 1.        ,  1.41421356,  1.73205081])
```

If this is a performance bottleneck, this is unlikely to be competetive with hand-written C++ code: First of all, you're manipulating python objects with all the overhead; then numpy is likely doing a bunch of array allocations under the hood.

An often viable strategy is to start by writing things in python/numpy, and then move bottlenecks into a compiled code --- eg Cython or C++ wrapped by Cython. In this particular case since you already have the C++ code, just wrapping it with Cython is likely easiest but YMMV.

Comment: ev-br: In the code that I want, the number of iteration of the Newton method depends upon u. Here, the number of iterations is global.

Comment: @InsideLoop: the best you can do with the vectorized approach is something along the lines of `while (dx < eps).all()`, where both `dx` and `eps` are arrays. This indeed iterates *all* components as long as *any one* of them has not converged.

Comment: Actually, you can iterate unconverged components only by using a boolean array `mask = dx < eps`: `x[mask] -= v[mask] / dv[mask]`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not looking to wave small snippets of code as a solution, but here's something to get you started. I have a strong suspicion that you're having troubles just declaring such an array in python without spending too much time on it, so I'll mostly help you out there.

As far as the square roots come in, please add your example python code and I'll see what I can help optimize from that point on. In my example roots and sums are found with the default numpy functions/methods.

```
def summing():
    n = 1000000
    ar = np.arange(0, n)
    ar = ar/float(n)
    ar = ar + np.ones(n)
    sqrt = np.sqrt(ar)
    return np.sum(ar)
```

In short, to get the starting array it's best to use a "workaround".

- initialize an array `ar` with values `[1,2,3,....n]
- divide `ar` with `n`. This gets us the  `1/n, 2/n ...` members
- add to that an array of same dimensions that contain just the number `1.0`
  This gets us the full array `[ 1., 1.000001, 1.000002, ..., 1.999998, 1.999999])` we're after. If I understood you right.
- find square roots, sum it

Average of 10 sequential execution times is `0.018786` seconds.

Comment: My code is a "short version" of the real code and the function I am trying to inverse does not have an inverse function in closed form.

Answer (score 0):

Obviously I'm 6 years late to this party, but this question is a common stumbling block for people in effectively using numpy for real scientific work.  The basic idea is covered in @ev-br's answer.  The OP points out that the solution offered there (even modified to stop iterating when a convergence criterion is met rather than after a fixed number of iterations) takes the same number of passes for each element of u.  I want to show how you can avoid that objection using pure numpy code, making explicit the mask suggestion in @ev-br's comment.

However, I also want to point out that in many real world situations, the number of passes for Newton-like iteration to converge varies so little that this general technique I illustrate here will actually slow numpy code down significantly.  If the average number of iterations will be within a factor of two or three of the maximum number of iterations, you should stick with something closer to @ev-br's answer (including his first comment).

The numpy performance numbers you need to understand are these: Loops over array indices will run 200 to 500 times slower in pure numpy code than in compiled code.  On the other hand, if you manage to use numpy's array syntax to avoid all index loops, you can get within about a factor of 5 of compiled speed.  (The factor of 5 is partly because of memory management as @ev-br mentions, but also because optimized compiled code overlaps many different arithmetical operations inside each index loop, while numpy just performs a single arithmetic operation, storing everything back to memory after each operation.)  The point is that factor of 100 difference means that it often pays to do substantial amounts of "extra" work in numpy code: Even if you do 10 times the number of floating point operations in vectorized numpy code, it will still run 10 times faster than the index-loop code that avoids the "extra" work.  (Incidentally, the python map function is implemented as an interpreted index loop - it has nothing to do with numpy array operations.)

```
from numpy import asfarray, broadcast_arrays, arange

# Begin by defining the function to be inverted by Newton's method.
def f_dfdx(x):
    x = asfarray(x)  # always avoid repeated type conversions
    return x**2, 2.*x

# First, the simplest algorithm to find x such that f(x)=y.
# We must supply a starting guess x0 for x.
def f_inverse0(f_dfdx, y, x0, tol=1.e-7):
    y, x = broadcast_arrays(asfarray(y), asfarray(x0))
    x = x.copy()  # without this may clobber input x0
    for npass in range(20):
        f, dfdx = f_dfdx(x)
        dx = (f - y) / dfdx
        if (abs(dx) <= tol).all():
            break  # iterate all x until all have converged
        x -= dx
    else:
        raise RuntimeError("failed to converge")
    return x

# A frequently slower algorithm that avoids extra iterations.
def f_inverse1(f_dfdx, y, x0, tol=1.e-7):
    y, x = broadcast_arrays(asfarray(y), asfarray(x0))
    shape = x.shape
    y, x = y.ravel(), x.flatten()  # avoid clobbering x0
    unconverged = arange(y.size)
    for npass in range(20):
        f, dfdx = f_dfdx(x[unconverged])
        dx = (f - y[unconverged]) / dfdx
        unc = abs(dx) > tol
        unconverged = unconverged[unc]
        if not unconverged.size:
            break  # iterate all x until all have converged
        x[unconverged] -= dx[unc]
    else:
        raise RuntimeError("failed to converge")
    return x.reshape(shape)
```

On my machine, the OP's C++ program runs in 2.03 s (1.64+0.38 user+sys).  For n=100 million as for the C++ program, f_inverse0 runs in 20.4 s (4.7+15.6 user+sys).  As expected, f_inverse1 is slower, 51.3 s (11.5+39.8 user+sys).  Again, don't automatically try to minimize total operation count when you are writing numpy code.  The high system overhead is probably due to heavy memory management - every vector temporary is 0.8 GB and the memory manager is struggling.

Cutting the array size to n = 1 million elements (8 MB), then multiplying the runtime by 100 brings the system time down by a large factor, f_inverse0 now takes 16.1 s (12.5+3.6), while f_inverse1 takes 22.3 s (16.2+5.1).  This factor of 8 to 10 slower than compiled code is not unreasonable to expect for numpy performance.